# Logging into site using Selenium stopped working

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have been using a python script and the Selenium library to log into Linkedin for several months now.  In the past week, it is no longer working.

I cannot figure out what is going on.  It does not appear that Linkedin has renamed any fields.

Here is my code snippet:

```
#define URL and launch firefox
mainURL='https://www.linkedin.com/'
browser=webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(mainURL)
time.sleep(5)

#first log into linkedin.com
try:
    emailElem = browser.find_element_by_id('login-email')
    emailElem.send_keys('username')
except:
    print('Was not able to find an element with the login-email id name.')

try:
   passwordElem=browser.find_element_by_id('login-password')
   passwordElem.send_keys('password')
   passwordElem.submit()
except:
   print('Was not able to find an element with the login-password id name.')

time.sleep(5)
```

Any help would be appreciated as I am a coding novice and can't figure out what has changed.

Comment: Share exception log

Comment: you should add the output log too

Comment: @Andersson   Here is what is says:   ERROR:root:message
...
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Expected [object Undefined] undefined to be a string

Comment: Take some time to learn how to debug your code. Once you do that, you will be able to solve issues like this on your own.

Comment: Have you tried updating Selenium and the Firefoxdriver?

Comment: @simon Baars.  I just tried your suggestion.  I agree that it might be a likely cause because it strangely stopped working after several weeks.  Unfortunately, now I have run into another strange issue.  I have successfully upgraded Selenium and I put an updated gecko driver in a folder specified in my path (/Users/admin/anaconda/bin:) but it still says "WebDriverException: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH. "  Sorry for the new question but this is frustrating.

Comment: @SimonBaars: I just wanted to update you.  I was able to figure out the webdriver issue.  And more good news:  Updating Selenium and the geckodriver fixed the issue!  Thanks so much for your thoughtful advice.

Comment: @user3003374 Great to hear it helped. I created an answer to this question to make future people reading this question so they don't have to read all the comments. If you could accept the answer that would be great :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issues like these (something that worked suddenly not working anymore) are most commonly caused by outdated drivers. Updating your Firefox driver will help.

Updating the Firefox driver most of the time also requires Selenium to be updated. If you do that the problem should most likely be solved.